# How to add functions to a class based on a parameter

Tags: python, class, function

I've got a class (`node`) to which I want to assign a specific set of functions (in this case `a1`, `a2`, `b1`, and `b2`) based on a parameter of the class (`operatingMode`).

The situation is that I have a motor that has many different operating modes. Each operating mode allows for certain functions to be performed, but not others. The assignment of functions to various modes is done in a way that does not lend itself nicely to creating classes for each operating mode.

Below is my pass at a solution, but it doesn't work.

Any thoughts?

```
def a1(self):
    return 'a1'

def a2(self):
    return 'a2'

def b1(self):
    return 'b1'

def b2(self):
    return b2




class node(object):
    def __init__(self,operatingMode):
    self.operatingMode=operatingMode

    if self.operatingMode=='A':
        self.a1function=a1
        self.a2function=a2
        print 'Operating Mode \'A\' functions loaded'

    if self.operatingMode=='B':
        self.b1function=b1
        self.b2function=b2
        print 'Operating Mode \'B\' functions loaded'

    def setOperatingMode(self,operatingMode):
        self.operatingMode=operatingMode
        self.__init__(self,operatingMode)
```

Running this in my terminal lets me call it, but I have to state elbow twice:

```
In [65]: elbow=node('A')
Operating Mode 'A' functions loaded

In [66]: elbow.a1function(elbow)
Out[66]: 'a1'
```

trying to run `elbow.setOperatingMode('B')` yields an error.

Comment: It's not totally clear what you're trying to achieve, but did you try `self.a1function = a1`, etc.?

Comment: +1 to @BrenBarn. Or, alternatively, maybe `self.functions = {}`, then `self.functions['a1'] = a1function`? Without knowing how you're hoping to _call_ these methods, it's hard to say how to do it right.

Comment: On another node: calling `__init__` from another method is usually a very bad idea. If you have code that you want called by both `__init__` and `setOperatingMode`, abstract it out into a method they both call (or have `__init__` call `setOperatingMode` instead of the other way around).

Comment: I made the change @BrenBarn mentioned (and updated the code appropriately. I've also added some commands so you can see what I'm trying to do. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just define `a1function`, `a2function`, etc. as plain old members, and maybe add a precondition check to give you an error when calling in the wrong state?

Comment: @abarnert This is for motor control, so I'm trying to limit overhead... operating modes will be changed much more infrequently than individual commands will be called.

Comment: @Chris: The overhead of comparing a string is much lower than the overhead of calling a method in the first place, so this is an extreme case of premature optimization.

Comment: @Chris: More importantly… if checking really _is_ too slow, you can just skip the check. As long as you never call `a1function` while in state `B`, who cares that it's there? Or, alternatively, instead of trying to create a complex `node` class that knows how to switch states, create a different class for each state, and just swap out the objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response to this comment:

> This is for motor control, so I'm trying to limit overhead...
>   operating modes will be changed much more infrequently than individual
>   commands will be called.

Python instances can change their class. You could use this to change operating modes without needing to use an `if`-clause to check the mode:

```
class Base(object):
    # Put any methods shared by ANode and BNode here.
    pass

class ANode(Base):
    def a1(self):
        return 'a1'

    def a2(self):
        return 'a2'

class BNode(Base):
    def b1(self):
        return 'b1'

    def b2(self):
        return 'b2'


elbow = ANode()
print(elbow.a1())
# a1

knee = ANode()
print(knee.a1())
# a1

elbow.__class__ = BNode
print(knee.a1())
# a1
print(elbow.b2())
# b2

elbow.a1()
# AttributeError: 'BNode' object has no attribute 'a1'
```

---

On the positive side, this is the fastest suggestion I've posted.
Notice there are no `if`-statements in the code above. Once the class changes, all the available methods change along with it "instantly", purely due to normal Python method calling semantics.

If `Node` is defined as in the decorator solution,

```
In [33]: elbow = Node('A')

In [34]: %timeit elbow.a1()
1000000 loops, best of 3: 288 ns per loop
```

While, if `knee` is defined using `ANode`,

```
In [36]: knee = ANode()

In [37]: %timeit knee.a1()
10000000 loops, best of 3: 126 ns per loop
```

So this solution is more than 2x as fast at calling methods than the decorator solution.

Switching speed is comparable:

```
In [38]: %timeit elbow.operatingMode = 'B'
10000000 loops, best of 3: 71.7 ns per loop

In [39]: %timeit knee.__class__ = BNode
10000000 loops, best of 3: 78.7 ns per loop
```

---

**Caveat**: One thing that is going to plague all the solutions I've posted is that after a switch *the names* the the available methods change. That means when you program using these classes, you have to keep track of the state of the instance before you can even know what methods are available. That is awkward.

Your program will be much much simpler if `ANode` and `BNode` have **exactly** the same interface -- all the same attribute and method names -- with just the definitions of those methods to changing (when the mode -- or class -- is changed).

---

Regarding this comment:

> I've got about a hundred functions and 7 operation modes. Of those
>   functions, about 10 are shared between all operation modes, 75 are
>   shared by multiple modes, and 15 are exclusive to a particular mode.
>   The problem is that the 75 aren't allocated to the modes nicely: Some
>   might be in modes 1,4 and 7, others in 2,4,5, and 7, others in 1 and
>   5.

You can define the methods outside the classes, and then "hook them up" to Mode-based classes like this:

```
def a1(self):
    return 'a1'

def a2(self):
    return 'a2'

def b1(self):
    return 'b1'

def b2(self):
    return 'b2'

class Base(object):
    # Put the 10 methods share by all modes here
    def common1(self): 
        pass

class ANode(Base):
    a1 = a1
    a2 = a2

class BNode(Base):
    b1 = b1
    b2 = b2

class CNode(Base):
    a1 = a1
    b2 = b2
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `types.MethodType` and `__getattr__`:

```
import types

def a1(self):
    return 'a1'

def a2(self):
    return 'a2'

def b1(self):
    return 'b1'

def b2(self):
    return 'b2'

class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, operatingMode):
        self.operatingMode = operatingMode
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        if self.operatingMode=='A':
            if attr == 'a1function':
                return types.MethodType(a1, self)
            if attr == 'a2function':
                return types.MethodType(a2, self)

        elif self.operatingMode=='B':
            if attr == 'b1function':
                return types.MethodType(b1, self)
            if attr == 'b2function':
                return types.MethodType(b2, self)
        else:
            raise AttributeError()
```

Then

```
elbow = Node('A')
print(elbow.a1function())
elbow.operatingMode = 'B'
print(elbow.b2function())
```

yields

```
a1
b2
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps using a `checkMode` decorator would be a cleaner way -- this avoids `__getattr__` and `type.MethodType` magic:

```
def checkMode(mode):
    def deco(func):
        def wrapper(self):
            if self.operatingMode == mode:
                return func(self)
            else:
                raise TypeError('Wrong operating Mode')
        return wrapper
    return deco

class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, operatingMode):
        self.operatingMode = operatingMode

    @checkMode('A')
    def a1(self):
        return 'a1'

    @checkMode('A')
    def a2(self):
        return 'a2'

    @checkMode('B')
    def b1(self):
        return 'b1'

    @checkMode('B')
    def b2(self):
        return 'b2'
```

with the code above, we can do this:

```
elbow = Node('A')
print(elbow.a1())
# a1

knee = Node('A')
print(knee.a1())
# a1

elbow.operatingMode = 'B'
print(knee.a1())  # knee is still in operatingMode A
# a1

print(elbow.b2())
# b2

elbow.a1()
# TypeError: Wrong operating Mode
```

---

**Explanation:**

The decorator syntax works as follows:

```
@deco
def func(): ...
```

is equivalent to

```
def func(): ...
func = deco(func)
```

Above, `checkMode` is a function which returns a decorator, `deco`.
`deco` then decorates the methods `a1`, `a2`, etc., so that

```
a1 = deco(a1)
```

Thus, `a1` is the func passed to `deco`. `deco(a1)`, in turn, returns a new method, generically called `wrapper`. This new method gets assigned to `a1` by the statement `a1 = deco(a1)`. So `a1` is now the method `wrapper`. So when you call `elbow.a1()`, the code in `wrapper` gets executed.

Comment: This seems to be working pretty well, and about 2x snappier than the method type approach. I'l have to do some digging on decorators to understand them a bit better

Comment: You might want to check out the `__class__` switching solution then. Calling the methods with that solution is by my measure more than 2x faster than this decorator solution since no `if`-statement has to be executed.

Comment: Unfortunately my list of functions doesn't break down so nicely that it accomodates discrete classes as shown... which is the impetus for this question in the first place.

Comment: Are you sure? It sounds as if you could "generate" the desired classes using mixins. If you can explain more about why the functions can't placed in discrete classes, we might be able to suggest a way around it.

Comment: So I've got about a hundred functions and 7 operation modes. Of those functions, about 10 are shared between all operation modes, 75 are shared by multiple modes, and 15 are exclusive to a particular mode. The problem is that the 75 aren't allocated to the modes nicely: Some might be in modes 1,4 and 7, others in 2,4,5, and 7, others in 1 and 5. It's this structure that has me thinking a single master class where I can include all functions and then filter out which ones are allowed might be best... having the operating mode as a parameter also maps well to my mental model of the system.

Comment: I think the class mode switching solution can work even in this situation. I'll update my post below to show what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Your entire design is very bizarre, and you probably need to take a step back and explain what you're trying to do so someone can help you with a better design.

But if you just want to make your design work, there are two problems with your current code:

```
self.a1function = a1
```

This sets `self.a1function` to a regular function, not a bound method. You can explicitly create a bound method like this:

```
self.a1function=types.MethodType(a1, self, self.__class__)
```

Or you can set `a1function` to be a wrapper around `a1`. Or, more simply, do the wrapping dynamically, which means you can fake the bound-method-ness with a closure, which is arguably more readable:

```
def __getattr__(self, attr):
    if attr == 'a1function' and self.operating_mode == 'A':
        return lambda: a1(self)
```

Meanwhile:

> trying to run elbow.setOperatingMode('B') yields an error.

You really need to post the traceback, or at least the error string, instead of just saying "yields an error". In this case, it tells you very explicitly what the error is, so you don't need to guess:

```
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

The problem is that in this line:

```
self.__init__(self,operatingMode)
```

… you're passing `self` twice. It's the object you call the method on, and it's also the first parameter.

Calling `__init__` from another method is a bad idea anyway, but if you really want to, it's the same as calling any other method:

```
self.__init__(operatingMode)
```